# What event handler can I use to capture new values that have been changed in a flex datagrid.

Tags: apache-flex, events, datagrid, itemeditor

I have an editable grid and would like to update values based on the edited cell and I am doing this in the `itemEditEndHandler` such that when they finish editing a cell I update other cells that are dependent on it. the only problem is in the `itemEditEndHandler` the new value has not registered yet. If I try and get the value of the cell i find that its still giving me the old value and not the new value that I have entered.

Answer (score 2):

Listen for [collectionChange](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#event%3acollectionChange) event on the `dataProvider` of the DataGrid.

`ListCollectionView` objects, i.e. ArrayCollection and XMLListCollection objects, dispatch a [CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.html) event whenever there is a change in the collection. Check for the [kind](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.html#kind) property of the dispatched event - if it is `CollectionEventKind.UPDATE`, it means that one or more items have been updated. The [items](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.html#items) array of the event will hold the updated items.

Answer (score 0):

If your datagrid is using a dataProvider that is an ArrayCollection, you can call its refresh() method in the handler triggered by the itemEditor's change event, then call the dataGrid's invalidateList() method.

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying to access certain values in a cell by using ListCollectionView(dgViewPreview.dataProvider).getItemAt(rowIndex)[Datafield] but its not returning the right values is there any other way. i am using this in the itemeditendhandler.

Answer (score 0):

Use *gridItemEditorSessionSave*

```
<s:DataGrid gridItemEditorSessionSave="dataGrid_gridItemEditorSessionSaveHandler(event)" >
...
...
...
</s:DataGrid>
```

and in the actionscript

```
protected function dataGrid_gridItemEditorSessionSaveHandler(event:GridItemEditorEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Edited");
            }
```